# How to bind a Java object with a table row in Spring using Thyemeleaf?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, thymeleaf

When the user clicks a button a new table row will be created via jQuery. At the same time an AJAX call goes out to my backend and creates a new object. I am trying to find a way to reference each row with its object created in the backend.

I have been thinking for a while now on the best way to do it with Thymeleaf or in Java and jQuery, but I have yet to find a way. Below is my code for when the user presses the button.

```js
function createSelectorData() {
  var search2 = {
    "dtoTiername": "Test"
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'text',
    url: "/ajax/createSelector",
    data: JSON.stringify(search2),
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("Success: " + result);
      $(".createTierRow").on("click", function(event) {
        $(".tAdd tbody").append(
          "<tr>" +
          "<td>New Selector</td>" +
          "<td><button class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger btnD\">Delete</button></td>" +
          "</tr>");
      });
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log("Errorr: " + err);
    }
  });
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping("/ajax/createSelector")
public @ResponseBody String getCreationSelector (@RequestBody TestApp mTestApp, HttpServletRequest request) 
{ 
  String val = mTestApp.getDtoTiername();       
  gpSelected.setSelectorToList(new SelectorDTO());
  System.out.println(gpSelected.getSelAryLength());
  // This object that is being returned, I want to associate it with my table row
  return Object; 
}
```